# Fallos al poner el comando npm en la terminal

Tags: javascript, nodejs, npm, webpack, terminal

hace poco inicie con webpack y npm. Así que me propuse a crear un programa de tareas con estas tegnologias, pero al poner el comando: "npm run build" en la terminal, me aparece el siguiente error 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero logren ayudarme y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Creo que falta un export amigo revisa esa parte donde es que te falta, normalmente deben ir en la parte inferior

Comment: Hola Gerardo, ya revise y al parecer no me falta ningún export, que mas crees que pueda ser?